# Game Map Viewer MouseX,Y to Long,Latitude

Tags: delphi, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I am not sure how to word this correctly however i have been working on a map viewer that loads a bitmap file to a Direct2D surface. However i want the map viewer mouse X,Y coordinates to match those similar to the game coordinates.

Here is a sample picture of what i am referring to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOaxG.png

The left map viewer is a separate application, i am trying to mimic this in my own map viewer, however you can see i am at the bottom left corner on both forms, and the coordinates do not match the Lon/Lat of my map viewer.

We are 4624 pixels wide, the bottom left corner should convert to Lon: 16384 Lat: 24577  whilst the top right hand corner will convert to Lon: 90111 Lat: 98304

```
var
  BSize: TD2DSizeF;
  S4, S5: string;
  FPos: TPoint;
begin
  S4 := 'Longitude: '+FloatToStr((BSize.Width / 360) * (180 + FPos.X));
  S5 := 'Latitude: '+FloatToStr((BSize.Height / 180) * (90 - FPos.Y));
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to work this out? Am i misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: I'd calculate first a number between 0-1 that's the amount across (x) or up/down (Y) across the whole image - eg 0 is left, 1 is right. Then, multiply that by the width and add the leftmost coordinate, and ditto for the height and bottommost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the formulae should be:

```
Lon := 16384 + x / MaxX * (90111 - 16384);
Lat := 98304 - y / MaxY * (98304 - 24577);
```

Where `MaxX` and `MaxY` are the pixel coordinates of the low-right corner (i.e. `Width - 1` and `Height - 1`, respectivelly).

Comment: I suspect if the image was in Zoom, i would need to divide that formula by the Zoom? `Lon := (16384 + FPos.X) / (ClientWidth - 1) * (90111 - 16384) / FZoom;`

Comment: If the Latitudes and Longitudes of the corners are the same, the only thing that changes is MAxX (i.e. NewWidth - 1) and MaxY (i.e. NewHeight - 1).

Comment: But, I suspect thet by zooming you assume that the window will remain the same, while the Lalitudes and Longitudes would change. In that case, you should just replace the new corner Lat/Lon in formulae above.